# Multiple Imputations with Panel Corrected Standard Errors in R

Tags: r, panel-data, imputation

Is there a way to combine results using panel corrected standard errors (pcse package) on multiply imputed datasets (Amelia II)?

For example I want to combine the results of the following models:

```
reg.pcse1 <- pcse(reg1, groupN = a.outt2$imputations[[1]]$country, groupT = a.outt2$imputations[[1]]$pyear, pairwise=TRUE)

reg.pcse2 <- pcse(reg2, groupN = a.outt2$imputations[[2]]$country, groupT = a.outt2$imputations[[2]]$pyear, pairwise=TRUE)
```

I tried computing the Pooled Estimates and Pooled Standard Errors using Rubin's rules, but I ran into trouble calculating the test statistic and p-values for a multivariate model by hand.

Comment: One possible method would be to wrap whatever you are "calculating" by hand into a function or functions. You would then be able to run these functions over multiple scenarios.

Comment: I managed to do this with the estimates and the SEs, but I have trouble into figuring out the formula used for pooling test statistics over multiple imputations. I am using a linear multivariate model and I don't know how to calculate the Wald test in this case. That is why I thought there might be some package or way to deal with this.

Comment: One well-accepted method for inference would be the bootstrap.